# How can I show only selected items in SwiftUI List?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, editmode

How can I make a List show a set of selected items when editMode is .inactive and all selectable options when editMode is .active so the user can change the set of selected items? Here is what I have tried:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectionView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    @State var selectedItems = Set<String>(["1-item", "2-item", "3-item", "4-item"])
    let allItems = ["1-item", "2-item", "3-item", "4-item"]
    var items: [String] {
        if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
            return Array(selectedItems)
        }
        else {
            return allItems
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItems) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .navigationBarTitle("Items")
        }
    }
}
```

The selected array is now unordered as it is generated from a set and I eventually want to have it in the correct order. But I'm first trying to get the list to work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is approach how it works for me. Unfortunately it is not completely nice due to specifics of `List` internals (or bug)...

The idea is to switch containers of `List` filtering one of them based on selected items, and the switching itself depends on manual tracking of `EditMode`

Anyway it works (tested with Xcode 11.2/iOS 13.2, as well in Preview)

```
struct SelectionView: View {
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive // ! Needed manual to track states

    @State var selectedItems = Set<String>(["1-item", "2-item", "3-item", "4-item"])
    let allItems = ["1-item", "2-item", "3-item", "4-item"]
    var items: [String] {
        allItems.filter { self.selectedItems.contains($0) }
    }

    @State var applyFilter = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(applyFilter ? items : allItems, id: \.self,
                     selection: $selectedItems) { item in
                        Text(item)
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
                .navigationBarTitle("Items")
            }
//            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode) // << this is how it should be, but crash
            .environment(\.editMode, Binding<EditMode>(get: { self.editMode },
               set: {
                    self.editMode = $0

                    // !!! below is needed workaround, because applying filter directly
                    // on close EditMode result in crash due to cached List internals
                    // until switch EditMode animation is finished completely
                    if $0 == .inactive {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                            self.applyFilter = true
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.applyFilter = false
                    }
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Filtering items with selectedItems is nice, but having to use DispatchQueue is too hacky for my taste. Wish there was a cleaner solution.